# still getting CORS error after configuring Spring with CorsRegistry/@CrossOrigin

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-boot, cors

Configured Spring back end with both CorsRegistry configuration / @CrossOrigin and im still getting CORS error when sending XMLHttpRequest.

NOTE this is only happening when im sending a DELETE request. For GET and POST it seems to be working fine..

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="abouts",
                produces="application/json",
                consumes="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class AboutController {

    private AboutRepository aboutRepo;

    public AboutController(AboutRepository aboutRepo) {
        this.aboutRepo = aboutRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<About> getAbouts() {
        return aboutRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{aboutId}")
    public ResponseEntity<About> aboutById(@PathVariable("aboutId") Long id) {
        Optional<About> optAbout = aboutRepo.findById(id);
        if (optAbout.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(optAbout.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public About postAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
        return aboutRepo.save(about);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{aboutId}")
    public About putAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
        return aboutRepo.save(about);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{aboutId")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteEvent (@PathVariable("aboutId") Long aboutId) {
        try {
            aboutRepo.deleteById(aboutId);
        }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
function deleteAbout (e) {
    let id = e.target.getAttribute("id").slice(5);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {
        getAbouts();
    }
    xhr.open("DELETE","http://localhost:8080/abouts/" + id);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    xhr.send();
}

window.addEventListener("load", getAbouts);
```

Comment: Start by removing `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")` and 
    `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')` from your frontend JavaScript code. You’re doing a DELETE request, not sending any request body, so it makes no sense to set a Content-Type for the request. And the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header is a response header, not a request header. Setting it for a request is only going to cause things to break even further.

Comment: found it thanks though..

Comment: also JSON header is required because of the consumes anno on controller, seems like bad design but oh well atm. Removed ACAH header tho, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax error.. missing } on delete method, spring controller... sorry guys

worked after I fixed it

Comment: this was the reason why it wasn't working